# DEBUG:matplotlib.pyplot:Loaded backend qt5agg version unknown

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to run a script which plot some data.
But when I run it, it fails and I get this in the console :

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.

This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Abandon (core dumped)
```

In the log file I get this :

```
DEBUG:matplotlib.pyplot:Loaded backend qt5agg version unknown.
DEBUG:matplotlib.pyplot:Loaded backend Qt5Agg version unknown.
```

Here's some information :

Python version : 3.9.7

matplotlib version : 3.4.3

Has anyone encountered his issue before ?

Also I don't really understand what  is a backend in matplotlib.

**Edit :**

By executing `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python3 file_name.py` I got this :

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/manon/anaconda3/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/manon/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-xinerama.so.0: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Abandon (core dumped)
```

Comment: execute: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python your_app.py`

Comment: Hello, Ok I've edited my post... But I don't understand how it helps ?

Comment: 1. Copy the complete message. 2. Matplotlib uses backends for windows (Qt, tk, etc) so in your case you are trying to use Qt but you need to configure/install some dependency so you get that error message.

Comment: It's weird, I'm working on Ubuntu... How do you know which dependency I have to install or configure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I've solved my problem !!
I did `sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0`
and now it works fine.